# How can I get a count of rows that match a given year in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, calculated-columns

I have a project schedule model where I track launch dates and I want to just count the items that match a given year. In this specific case, I want to know how many projects are going to launch in 2014.

Seems pretty simple and I'm thinking the caffeine hasn't hit yet, but for the life of me, I can't get this one to happen. Much appreciated.

Something like this:

```
@launch_this_year = Project.where(project.launch_date > 12/31/2014)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code.

```
@launch_this_year = Project.where("extract(year from launch_at) = ?", 2014).count
```

Comment: brilliant! thank you. appreciate the help. the extract will be handy for other things i want to do with dates.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is around the date format.  Use YYYY-MM-DD instead of MM/DD/YYYY.  Also your date of 'launch_date > 12/31/2014' suggests 2015 dates, not 2014.

```ruby
@launch_this_year = Project.where('launch_date > ?', '2013-12-31').count
```

Alternatively, you could let rails convert the date format for you using DateTime.parse

```ruby
@launch_this_year = Project.where('launch_date > ?', DateTime.parse('12/31/2013')).count
```

Another item to consider is, in the above query if there are 2014 and 2015 projects, the above query would include both.  If you want strictly 2014 projects, then Bachan solution would work or you could add a date range condition:

```ruby
@launch_this_year = Project.where(launch_date: DateTime.parse('12/31/2013')..DateTime.parse('1/1/2015')).count
#=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `projects` WHERE (`projects`.`launch_date` BETWEEN '2013-12-31 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-01 00:00:00')
```